# How to migrate many applications to Spring-Boot? Strategy and links to guides, not details

Tags: spring-boot

I did quite a bit of research and gone through multiple Spring Boot tutorials, but none seem to cover the "overall strategy" and other "high level" questions.  I am hoping to get some guidance and links to appropriate guides/tutorials for those types of issues (not the typical "this is how you code" ones).

The following are some of those specific strategy/high level questions, although I'd welcome anything that you think I missed asking about:

1) It seems that the Eclipse-based STS IDE is probably the best open source tool available, so we are seriously considering it.  It seems to support both Git and Maven, but most tutorials seem to be Maven based.  Is it safe to say that at least initially it is better to use Maven as the repository?

2) We have many relatively small web applications.  From what I read the overhead of embedded Tomcat for that many applications would be excessive and therefore it would be best to use Spring Boot to build but deploy those apps in a Tomcat server.  Is that correct or is there a better way to handle *many* small webapps?  Can someone provide a link to a good guide/tutorial for how to adjust Spring Boot apps so that they can be deployed in a server?

3) Besides using many open source libraries/jars, we have several that we created ourselves (for example, to handle interfaces to our various internal systems).  In the past we only maintained one version of our jars (the latest), made sure that they were backward compatible, and always deployed a single shared instance to the server in order to avoid having a separate copy loaded into memory for each webapp.  I have the impression that will no longer be possible once we switch to Maven/SpringBoot.  Is that impression correct?  Or is it possible to still deploy a single instance of our shared libraries/jars to the server (once built with Spring Boot) and have that single instance accessed by every webapp?   If still possible... could you give me a link to a good guide/tutorial (if it exists)?

4) In the traditional XML-based Spring configuration it was easy to extract the few configuration items that were unique to DEV/PROD from the context.xml to individual DEV/PROD .properties files, making it very easy when we updated/deployed an application as the PROD properties file would typically remain untouched.  In SpringBoot it seems that all properties go into application.properties.  Is there a way to separate those properties into 3 files, for example application.properties for common configurations, while using something like applicationDEV.properties and applicationPROD.properties to hold those few properties that are server-specific?

Thank you in advance for the replies.

Comment: 1. IDE: For development, Spring Tool Suite or Intellij are your most popular options. I think Intellj is more lightweight and has some nice built in features.

Comment: 2. Source Control: GIT all the way

Comment: 3. Java Build Tools: Maven vs Gradle: I lean towards maven since its more friendly for integrating with many more products.

Comment: 4. Artifact Repository Manager: Private Maven vs Artificatory vs Nexus: it depends on complexity of what you have as software

Comment: Thank you Edwin, this helped a lot.

Comment: 5. Deployment strategy: single boot jars on distinct cloud container, or muliple jrs on one cloud instance or multiple spring apps as war artifiacts on single instance on same web applicatino like tomcat. i lean towards each app on their own light instance if you appliation is server-side heavy.  but multiple jars on same EC2 works sharing apache instance as a proxy. I like using Amazon Web Services and you may want to have a look at Code Star to give you a good start where it provides a out of the box source control, deployment pipeline and sample app to start right away.

Comment: 6. Shared libraries: i have my own private repository with versioned jars similar to mvnrepository. So each of my apps can pull in desired version of desired shared library. FOR POINT #3 not sure what your goal is? disk space should not be a concern. it is best not to have a hard requirement to keep all apps on same version

Comment: 6. Environment Properties: Spring boot supports defining env specific environment files like application-test.properties, application--prod.propertes etc.  through spring profiles. You can even activate specific components based on profile driven through profile annoations

Comment: Your plan and choices are really decided by current state of your application, number of developers, complexity of source, security requirements and so many other details.Give more detail and perhaps i can give you even more advice.